# Doctrine - Proxy entity is not properly updated

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, behat

## Scenario

- I have an entity `Device` which has a bidirectional *OneToMany* relation with `Attribute` entity
- I have a CLI process which listen for incoming requests and eventually does something sending back a response
- I have a Behat test which checks if a Device attribute has been properly changed sending a request to said listener

## Behat test

This is what happens:

1. I get a `Device` object from DB through Doctrine repository - the device has an `Attribute` collection not yet initialized (lazy loaded)
2. Since I need to know a property of a specific attribute, this specific attribute gets loaded from Doctrine and thus initialized - it's still a `Proxy` but has `__isInitialized__` set as `true`
3. I send a request to the listener asking a change on this specific device attribute
4. The listener receives the request and change the attribute value as requested (e.g. `attribute->setValue(true)`)
5. The listener sends back a response to confirm the change
6. Now the test fetches the attribute for given device through `Attribute` entity repository in order to check if its value has been properly changed in DB from the listener

The problem comes at point 6: **attribute's value is wrong**.

Now someone might think it's normal since the object is already loaded and marked as initialized in Behat test so Doctrine is not aware of changes done by concurrent processes and this would fine.

However what is really strange is that Doctrine is executing anyway a query at point 6 (checked with Doctrine SQL logging) and this query is returning a result set which contains different values for that device attribute (ie. a different `value` property) but the attribute variable is not automatically updated!

In fact in order to update it I have to call `$em->refresh()` on the attribute or clear the cache using `$em->clear()` before fetching attribute at point 6.

Is this a bug in Doctrine or what? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer I was looking for.

Debugging through Doctrine classes (specifically in `UnitOfWork::createEntity()`) I found out that Doctrine won't overwrite existing entity data unless the query explicitly specifies a `Query::HINT_REFRESH` hint:

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('e')
    ->from(MyEntity::class, 'e')
    ->getQuery()->setHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true)->getResult();
```

This way Doctrine will overwrite entity properties if there's new DB data available for this entity even if the entity was already loaded in memory. Moreover this doesn't fire a new query like `$em->refresh()` does.

In fact this is also confirmed by [official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-hints):

> Query::HINT_REFRESH - This query is used internally by
>   EntityManager::refresh() and can be used in userland as well. If you
>   specify this hint and a query returns the data for an entity that is
>   already managed by the UnitOfWork, the fields of the existing entity
>   will be refreshed. In normal operation a result-set that loads data of
>   an already existing entity is discarded in favor of the already
>   existing entity.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for self-providing the solution you came up to. I'd like to reopen your topic with my problem about the *Doctrine proxy not being up-to-date* :

**TL;DR** : I have added a parameter to an entity method and now I have the error message telling me "the proxy entity method should be compatible with the entity method" :

> Warning: Declaration of Proxies_*CG*_\AppBundle\Entity\Affair\Affair::resetNumber() should be compatible with AppBundle\Entity\Affair\Affair::resetNumber($lastAffairId)

Is there a way to force the doctrine proxy update ?

**The long story** : in the legacy code, there is an object created, an "Affair". There is a listener waiting for the Affair to be persisted in DB, then the listener call the entity method resetNumber() to generate the reference of the object after some user defined parameters.
Today, this reference shall also depend on the last Affair previously created . So the listener retrieve the reference of the last created Affair, through the repository, and give it to the resetNumber() method as parameter. But the doctrine generated proxy entity won't update with the new resetNumber() methods.